# Symfony2. HWIOauth. Vkontakte. Get profile photo url

Tags: symfony, oauth, sdk, photo, hwioauthbundle

I can't get profile photo. Any Ideas?

```
# Some part from config.yml

hwi_oauth:
    firewall_names: [secured_area]
    resource_owners:
        vkontakte:
            type:                vkontakte
            client_id:           <client_id>
            client_secret:       <client_secret>
            scope:               "photo_50,email"

...
```

I get all other standard parameters when I log to the site with vk button. Such as: first_name, last_name, email, vk id etc.
A field "photo_50" => NULL
[image: Response Screenshot]
Response Screenshot

Comment: When I comment out 'scope' parameter in config.yml, result stay as image above.

Comment: I found solution. I corrected class "HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\ResourceOwner\VkontakteResourceOwner.php". Edited "photo" to "photo_50". Who knows another good solution without hardcoding vendors files?

Answer (score 0):

You need this configuration in your `app/config/config.yml`:

`hwi_oauth:
    resource_owners:
        vkontakte:
            type: vkontakte
            client_id: %id%
            client_secret: %secret%
            scope: "email"
            paths:
                profilepicture: response.0.photo_big
            options:
                fields: "photo_big"`